# How to find average of a particular field in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am experimenting in Scala shell in Apache Spark.
I have a text file with list of values and I want to find average of a particular column. My input.txt file looks as below. ( This is not the entire file, but a sample.)

```
1   12.4   12.5   18.9   19.9
2   1.7    1.9
3   11.99  1.9    8.9    12.90978933
2   89.987  7.99         12.898980800000
1   12.8    1.88  1.8
2   1.9     1.8   1.8979  1.808888
```

I want to find average of the 5th column per each column in 1st. For an example, assume that these are set of student ids and marks. For each student Id, I want to find marks of the last subject. Also please note that some values are missing in the last column.

This is the code I have tried so far.

```
val text = sc.textFile("/neerja/input.txt")
val data = text.flatMap(line => line.split("\\t")).map(word => (word,1).reduceByKey(_ + _);
```

I want to get the last column and find average.
As the first step, I thought of getting all the values in the last column.

```
val fourth = text.map(_.split("\\t")(4)).collect
```

but this gives me `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`. I am suspecting it happens because some values are missing in the last column. Please help me to find the average of the last column. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do simply the following

```
val text = sc.textFile("/neerja/input.txt")

val fourth = text.map(line => line.split("\\t"))
      .map(arr => Try(arr(4).toDouble) getOrElse(0.0)).mean()

println(fourth)
```

you should get the average of the 5th column subject

**updated**

If average of all the subject columns are required, I would suggest you to create `dataframe`. `Dataframe`s are optimized `RDD` and many *inbuilt functions* are available for computation.

For creating a `dataframe` for the data given you would require a `schema`.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DoubleType, IntegerType, StructField, StructType}
val schema = StructType(Seq(
  StructField("Sn", IntegerType, true),
  StructField("subject1", DoubleType, true),
  StructField("subject2", DoubleType, true),
  StructField("subject3", DoubleType, true),
  StructField("subject4", DoubleType, true)
))
```

`RDD[Row]` needs to be created as

```
val data = text.map(line => line.split("\\t"))
  .map(arr => Row.fromSeq(Seq(arr(0).toInt, Try(arr(1).asInstanceOf[DoubleType]) getOrElse(0.0),Try(arr(2).toDouble) getOrElse(0.0),Try(arr(3).toDouble) getOrElse(0.0),Try(arr(4).toDouble) getOrElse(0.0))))
```

finally dataframe is created

```
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data, schema)
```

*average* of each columns can be calculated by using `mean` function as

```
df.select(mean("subject1").as("averageOFS1"),mean("subject2").as("averageOFS2"),mean("subject3").as("averageOFS3"),mean("subject4").as("averageOFS4")).show(false)
```

which should give you `dataframe`

```
+------------------+-----------------+-----------+-----------------+
|averageOFS1       |averageOFS2      |averageOFS3|averageOFS4      |
+------------------+-----------------+-----------+-----------------+
|21.796166666666668|4.661666666666666|5.24965    |7.919609688333335|
+------------------+-----------------+-----------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ramesh Maharjan. This certainly helped me. Hoewever I am getting an answer like this.

 "scala> val fourth = text.map(line => line.split("\\t")).map(arr => Try(arr(4).toDouble) getOrElse(0.0)).mean()
fourth: Double = 0.5828306100675447

Which is the average value of the 4th column. What I really want is the average value "per" subject. For an example,my expected output be something like this. (per subject, average) 

1, 19.9
2,7.3539344
3,12.90978933

Comment: my pleasure :) @NeerjaSkyler, don't forget to upvote when you would be eligible

Comment: sure,will do :)

Comment: getOrElse(0.0) is probably a bad idea. Instead you should filter out the empty/non-double values in a first step, and then calculate the mean value.

Comment: Yes I agree with @RickMoritz , better answer is to use sqlContext as I have answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47592765/finding-average-value-in-spark-scala-gives-blank-result/47593705#47593705)

Answer (score 0):

If you do wanna try a structural approach to this you could also achieve this using Dataframes:

```
object average extends App{

  val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder
    .master("local")
    .appName("example")
    .getOrCreate()

  import sparkSession.implicits._


      val x = sparkSession.read
        .option("header", "false")
        .option("delimiter", "\\t")
        .option("mode", "FAILFAST")
        .csv("...Spark-2.x/src/main/resources/tab_data.csv")

x.printSchema()
x.show(truncate = false)
 val df: DataFrame =  x.select('_c0 as "id",
'_c1 as "sub1",'_c2 as "sub2",'_c3 as "sub3",'_c4 as "sub4")

  df.groupBy('id).agg(avg('sub4)).show()
}
```