# Finding average value in spark scala gives blank result

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a input.txt file. Data looks as below.

```
1   1383260400000   0   0.08136262351125882             
1   1383260400000   39  0.14186425470242922 0.1567870050390246  0.16093793691701822 0.052274848528573205    11.028366381681026
1   1383261000000   0   0.13658782275823106         0.02730046487718618 
1   1383261000000   33                  0.026137424264286602
2241    1383324600000   0   0.16869936142032646             
2241    1383324600000   39  0.820500491400199   0.6518011299798726  1.658248219576473   3.4506242774863045  36.71096470849049
2241    1383324600000   49  0.16295028249496815
```

Assume the first column is  id and other columns are col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6 and col7 respectively.I want to find average for the col7 for each id. Basically I want my results in,
id, avg of col7 format.

This is the code I have tried so far.
I read my data in txt file.
Then I created a schema.

```
val schema = StructType(Seq(
  StructField("ID", IntegerType, true),
  StructField("col1", DoubleType, true),
  StructField("col2", IntegerType, true),
  StructField("col3", DoubleType, true),
  StructField("col4", DoubleType, true),
  StructField("col5", DoubleType, true),
  StructField("col6", DoubleType, true),
  StructField("col7", DoubleType, true)
))
```

Then I created a data frame.

```
val data = text.map(line => line.split("\\t")).map(arr => Row.fromSeq(Seq(arr(0).toInt,Try(arr(1).asInstanceOf[DoubleType]) getOrElse(0.0),Try(arr(2).toInt) getOrElse(0),Try(arr(3).toDouble) getOrElse(0.0),Try(arr(4).toDouble) getOrElse(0.0),Try(arr(5).toDouble) getOrElse(0.0),Try(arr(6).toDouble) getOrElse(0.0),Try(arr(7).asInstanceOf[DoubleType]) getOrElse(0.0))))
```

Finally save in a txt file.

```
val res1 = df.groupBy("ID").agg(avg("col7"))

res1.rdd.saveAsTextFile("/stuaverage/spoutput12")
```

When I run this I get several file with blank results. 
e.g.

```
[1068,0.0]
[1198,0.0]
[1344,0.0]
[1404,0.0]
[1537,0.0]
[1675,0.0]
[1924,0.0]
[193,0.0]
[211,0.0]
[2200,0.0]
[2225,0.0]
[2663,0.0]
[2888,0.0]
[3152,0.0]
[3235,0.0]
```

First column is correct. But for the second column, I should get a value. 
(although  values are missing for some rows)

Please help.

Comment: There is a problem with the data format. Sometimes there is a space, some other times there is a tabulation or a double tabulation... So what's actually happening is something like the following : `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1   1383260400000   0   0.08136262351125882             "` but since you are using Try().getOrElse, all of your values are `else` but you cannot catch the error. You need to give a corrected data format where there is actually just one tabulation to separate.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I don’t need to.

Comment: Ok :) because you commented yesterday on the answer with negative thoughts . I thought you downvoted. sorry for my misunderstanding. But I am surprised that somebody downvoted without even understanding the answer.

Comment: I wrote you yesterday that I don’t think that your answer isn’t correct but that the OP has other issues which I explained in my comments. It seems to have had worked for him. My comments still stand. You’ve been around for a while. I don’t criticize as a negative comment, but tricky was rude... I don’t like rude ppl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use sqlContext api and use the schema you have defined

```
val df = sqlContext.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("delimiter", "\\t")
  .schema(schema)
  .load("path to your text file")
```

the schema is

```
val schema = StructType(Seq(
  StructField("ID", IntegerType, true),
  StructField("col1", DoubleType, true),
  StructField("col2", IntegerType, true),
  StructField("col3", DoubleType, true),
  StructField("col4", DoubleType, true),
  StructField("col5", DoubleType, true),
  StructField("col6", DoubleType, true),
  StructField("col7", DoubleType, true)
))
```

After that all you need is to apply `avg` function on the grouped `dataframe` as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val res1 = df.groupBy("ID").agg(avg("col1"),avg("col2"),avg("col3"),avg("col4"),avg("col5"),avg("col6"),avg("col7"))
```

finally you can save directly to `csv` from `dataframe`. You don't need to convert to `rdd`

```
  res1.coalesce(1).write.csv("/stuaverage/spoutput12")
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you convert `col7` the wrong way, you try to cast it to `DoubleType` instead of parsing it to a scala `Double` (using `.toDouble`). Your cast will always throw an Exception, and thus `col7` will always be 0.0. This works:

```
val rdd = sqlContext.textFile("input.txt")
  .map(line => line.split("\\t"))
    .map((arr: Array[String]) => Row(
    arr(0).toInt,
    Try(arr(1).toDouble) getOrElse (0.0),
    Try(arr(2).toInt) getOrElse (0),
    Try(arr(3).toDouble) getOrElse (0.0),
    Try(arr(4).toDouble) getOrElse (0.0),
    Try(arr(5).toDouble) getOrElse (0.0),
    Try(arr(6).toDouble) getOrElse (0.0),
    Try(arr(7).toDouble) getOrElse (0.0)
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this a bit more concise version (assuming you work from spark-shell). It should work.

```
val df = spark
  .read
  .option("header","false")
  .option("sep","\t")
  .option("inferSchema","true")
  .csv("...input...")
  .toDF("ID","col1","col2","col3","col4","col5","col6","col7")

val result = df.groupBy("ID").mean("col7")

result
  .write
  .option("header","true")
  .option("sep",";")
  .csv("...output...")
```

Comment: Konstantin Kotochigov : Can you please explain how this will calculate average for the col7? I want per ID, col7 average.

Comment: I missed an argument in code, it should by mean("col7") of course. groupBy("ID") will group records per each ID and mean("col7") will compute average of the column.

Comment: The issue is what I stated in my comment under the question.